# Django app can't upload multi-band-image

Tags: python, python-2.7, multi-band, django

I try to upload a TIFF raster image with 5 bands in Django app and I get error message in form : `Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image.` I am sure that image is valid .

Here the code :

```
def dataset(request):
    uploadimages = UploadImagesForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if uploadimages.is_valid():
        if request.FILES.get('multipleimages', None) is not None:
            images = request.FILES.getlist('multipleimages')
            for image in images:
                name = str(image)
                .........
    return render(request, 'mylist.html', {'uploadimages': uploadimages})
```

forms.py

```
class UploadImagesForm(forms.Form):
    multipleimages = forms.ImageField(label="Upload Multiple Images:",widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}), required=False)
```

Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: There is not enough information here. Where is the error coming from? The code that you've posted is not specific enough. Maybe look in the `UploadImagesForm` object? Or the validators on it, perhaps? If it's code in your Django app, you'll need to trace it through. We can't see any of that code, though!

Comment: @Alex Leith I have update my question with UploadImagesForm